# Objective-c converting string to double results null

Tags: objective-c, string, double

I am writing an app where the user inputs numeric values that are summed. When I attempt to convert the input from a string to a double, the result is null. For example:

```
 NSString *firstString = stringTextbox.text;
 NSLog(@"the first string is %@", firstString);

 double firstDouble = [firstString doubleValue];
 NSLog(@"the first double is %@", firstDouble);
```

The first log shows the correct input, but the second NSLog() call shows "null".

Answer (score 6):

`%@`is a format string for [outputting objects, not doubles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1). You should instead use `%f`.

Comment: Thanx a lot! Have to be more attentive next time =)